# Does the instances of a class still share the same static members between thread inside the same process?

Tags: c++, operating-system

That is what's the scope of sharing static members?

Comment: C++ doesn't care about threads (C++11 has thread support though).

Comment: @iammilind I am a fresh in unix programing. Why people say multiple threads is not supported before C++11? Isn't the pthread_t class is provided in /user/include/pthread.h?

Comment: Threads were not discussed in the standard before C++11 therefore they were not considered part of the language. pthreads is an orthogonal library that provides support for threads. C++11 - the latest version of the standard - introduces the concept of threads to C++, heavily based on the work in the Boost thread library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `static` storage duration implies that the variable in question comes into existence when the process is started and is deallocated not before the end of the process. It is shared by all threads of the process, and accessing it can cause data races between the threads, just like with a global variable.

C++11 introduced a new storage duration specifier `thread_local`, the use of which implies that there is one instance of the variable in each individual thread. It is allocated when the thread begins.

Unfortunately none of the major compilers (GCC, Clang, VC++) has implemented this fully yet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a class `static` member is shared across all instances of that class. It's scope can be restricted by marking it `public`, `protected` or `private`. If you are going to have multiple threads simultaneously accessing/mutating the `static` member then you will need to synchronise this access, e.g. via mutexes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, threading doesn't influence static storage. You can think of `static` members as globals. So modifying a `static` is not thread-safe, something to think about.